# Force.com Enterprise WSDL in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, salesforce

Does anyone know how to use Force.com Enterprise WSDL in iphone?
I want to retrive calendar events also from force.com

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to use the WSDL directly, you'll be better off using one of the existing libraries, try [zkSforce](https://github.com/superfell/zkSforce) or the [iOS toolkit](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-iOS)